# Python :Remove items that are less than 4 characters

Tags: python, pandas, character, items

I have a data frame as shown below:

I need to delete items that are less that 4 characters from the column CityIds. There could be spaces after comma, as there are thousands of elements under Items.

| CityIds |
| --- |
| 98765, 98-oki, th6, iuy89, 8.90765 |
| 89ol, gh98.0p, klopi, th, loip |
| 98087,PAKJIYT, hju, yu8oi, iupli |

For example: I want to remove th6 or show th6 in a separate column.

Comment: add a few more testable rows (if it's more than 1 row in dataset)

Comment: The screenshot and mention of "columns" makes me think you're using pandas dataframes. Is that correct? Dataframes aren't a native Python data type. When asking questions about pandas, please always include the [tag:pandas] tag, as described in the Python tag wiki: "When using a Python variant (e.g. Jython, PyPy) or library (e.g. Pandas, NumPy), please include it in the tags."

Comment: @Chris, that's not a screenshot, just a too small 1-row fragment

Comment: Oh geez, you're right. It's rendering fuzzy on my screen for some reason... Still isn't a [mre], though. At the very least, OP needs to confirm that they are using pandas and dataframes, and ideally the data should still be reformatted such that we can easily copy and paste it.

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] to include a [mre] showing your code and any wrong output or error messages

Comment: I edited the question, let me know if that is making sense. I tried this: [i for i in df["CityIds"] if len(i) >= 4]

Answer (score 0):

answer above is obviously cleaner; but, here I added a new column for excluded IDs:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'CityIds': ['98765, 98-oki, th6, iuy89, 8.90765',
                 '89ol, gh98.0p, klopi, th, loip',
                 '98087, PAKJIYT, hju, yu8oi, iupli']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
n = len(df['CityIds'])
df['rmvdIDs'] = ['' for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    row = df['CityIds'][i]
    cityIDs = "".join(row.split()).split(',')
    new_IDs = [i for i in cityIDs if len(i) >= 4]
    excl_IDs = list(set(cityIDs) - set(new_IDs))
    new_row = ", ".join(new_IDs)
    excl_row = ", ".join(excl_IDs)
    df['CityIds'][i] = new_row
    df['rmvdIDs'][i] = excl_row

print(df)
```

will return:

```
                         cityIDs rmvdIDs
0  98765, 98-oki, iuy89, 8.90765     th6
1     89ol, gh98.0p, klopi, loip      th
2   98087, PAKJIYT, yu8oi, iupli     hju
```

-- Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Extract and join back just the needed items those length is equal or greater than `4`:

```
df['CityIds'] = df['CityIds'].str.findall(r'([^\s,]{4,})').str.join(', ')
```

---

```
                         CityIds
0  98765, 98-oki, iuy89, 8.90765
1     89ol, gh98.0p, klopi, loip
2   98087, PAKJIYT, yu8oi, iupli
```

Comment: Thank you @Roman, I am new to all this, hence glad you patiently guided and thank you all.